# Как залить данные из xml в локальную базу mysql

Tags: mysql, xml, парсер, xmlparser

Привет. Дано: xml со множеством тегов.

База локальная mysql.

Создано несколько таблиц в соответствии с тегами xml.

Как раскидать файл xml в несколько таблиц базы?

Пробовал команду LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE - ругается на несовместимость версий.
Изменял базы с 5.1 на 5.5 и обратно. Толку никакого

Подскажите команду и синтаксис чтобы сопоставить xml теги с полями таблиц.

Пример xml. Руками править его каждый раз для чего-то не хотелось бы.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE yml_catalog SYSTEM "shops.dtd">
<yml_catalog><shop>
<currencies><currency id="RUR" rate="1" plus="0"/></currencies>
<categories>
<category id="6488" sort_order="0">MP3-плееры</category>
</categories>
<offers>
    <offer available="true" type="vendor.model" id="991">
        <categoryId>6488</categoryId><currencyId>RUR</currencyId>
        <description>Память: 4 ГБ</description><model>Fit 2</model>
        <name>Аксессуары Бренда</name><picture>http://site.ru/pic.jpg</picture>
    <price>999</price><url>http://site.ru/katalog/3D99110910</url>
        <vendor>Бренд</vendor>
</offer></offers></shop></yml_catalog>
```

И еще момент, если обрабатывать между `<offer></offer>`, то название категории будет 6488 и не вытаскивается ёё название MP3-плееры так как оно за пределами offer. Как быть?

Answer (score 1):

В MySQL 5.5 появилась [инструкция](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html) по импорту данных из XML в БД.

`LOAD XML INFILE 'data.xml' INTO TABLE tabble_name`

где `data.xml` может быть 3-х типов:

```
// 1 тип
<row column1="value1" column2="value2" .../>

// 2 тип
<row>
  <column1>value1</column1>
  <column2>value2</column2>
</row>

// 3 тип
<row>
  <field name='column1'>value1</field>
  <field name='column2'>value2</field>
</row>
```

Если ваш xml-файл содержит данные для 2-х и больше таблиц, то вам придется разбивать его на соответствующие кол-во частей. Или написать небольшой скрипт на bash, perl, php и тд.

Скрипт для парсинга:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
$xml_file = "data.xml";

if (file_exists($xml_file)) {
  $xml = simplexml_load_file($xml_file);
  $i=0;
  foreach ($xml->xpath("//currencies") as $segment) {
    $row = $segment->currency->attributes();
    $sql = "insert into currencies (id, rate,  plus) values('".$row["id"]."', ".$row["rate"].", ".$row["plus"].");";
    echo $sql."\n";
  }

  foreach ($xml->xpath("//categories/category") as $segment) {
    $row = $segment->attributes();
    $sql = "insert into categories (id, sort_order,  name) values(".$row["id"].", ".$row["sort_order"].", '".$segment."');";
    echo $sql."\n";
  }

  foreach ($xml->xpath("//offers/offer") as $segment) {
    $row = $segment->attributes();
    $sql = "insert into offers (id, available,  type, categoryId, model, name) values(".$row["id"].", ".$row["available"].", '".$row["type"]."',  ".$segment->categoryId.", '".$segment->model."', '".$segment->name."');";
    echo $sql."\n";
  }

} else {
  exit('Не удалось открыть файл '.$xml_file);
}

?>
```

Comment: Посмотрите xml соответствует или нет? Мне бы пример парсера или команды с разбором пары узлов xml-я. Далее я по аналогии добавил бы остальные поля

Comment: Конструкцию LOAD XML INFILE 'data.xml' INTO TABLE tabble_name я тоже видел, но никак не могу понять как сопоставлять поля в таблицах с узлами в xml, когда таблиц штук 15 и узлов столько же.

Comment: @Андрей: Ваш xml можно загнать в БД только через скрипт. 
Я вижу там 3 таблицы currencies, categories и offers в базе shop - верно?

Comment: Скорее всего вы правы. А то я все не понимал как с ними быть, а это оказывается 3 разных. Какой хоть командой разбирать это безобразие при условии что файл может быть очень большой?

Comment: @Андрей: Обновил свой ответ

Comment: А подскажите, где в этом скрипте название базы. Названия таблиц я понял "insert into currencies" - это currencies, categories и offers. А названия полей "insert into offers (id, available,  type, categoryId, model, name)" - это id, available,  type, categoryId, model, name и другие. И чтобы скрипт работал нужно просто убрать echo?

Comment: что-бы скрипт работал надо или вписать туда вызовы функция для работы с mysql (это я оставил вам) или весь вывод сохранить в файл и потом это файл скормить mysql:

`$ php parser.php > file.sql`

`$ mysql -u USER -pPASSWORD DB_NAME < file.sql`

Comment: ОО, нет )) я не настолько крут. Я видел sql запросы, но это дремучий лес....точно так же как файлы TPL. Помогите для //currencies например?!

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');
  foreach ($xml->xpath("//currencies") as $segment) {
    $row = $segment->currency->attributes();
    $sql = "insert into currencies (id, rate,  plus) values('".$row["id"]."', ".$row["rate"].", ".$row["plus"].")";
    $mysqli->query($sql);
    echo $sql."\n";
  }
$mysqli->close();`

Comment: @Борис Здравствуйте. Подскажите пожалуйста , а если это очень большой XML скажем 50ГБ , получится ли так сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Вы так понимаю заливаете файлы предназначенный для яндекса.
Выше описные способы не подходят - так как они генерят sql c предустановленным набором полей , а dtd схема подразумевает вариативность то есть массивы offer могут иметь разный набор полей . Не надо выдумывать никаких парсеров и велосипедов все уже придумано . Конвертируем xml в json и работаем с ним , после генерации массива получим :

```
Array
(
    [shop] => Array
        (
            [currencies] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => RUR
                                    [rate] => 1
                                    [plus] => 0
                                )

                        )

                )

            [categories] => Array
                (
                    [category] => MP3-плееры
                )

            [offers] => Array
                (
                    [offer] => Array
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [available] => true
                                    [type] => vendor.model
                                    [id] => 991
                                )

                            [categoryId] => 6488
                            [currencyId] => RUR
                            [description] => Память: 4 ГБ
                            [model] => Fit 2
                            [name] => Аксессуары Бренда
                            [picture] => http://site.ru/pic.jpg
                            [price] => 999
                            [url] => http://site.ru/katalog/3D99110910
                            [vendor] => Бренд
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Так как Вас скорее всего интересуют чисто товары то зальем его :

```
//Тут ваша строка xml
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$data = json_decode($json,TRUE);
//обойдем все товары
foreach($data['shop']['offers'] as $item) {
    //если есть атрибуты 
    if($item['@attributes']){
        $item['attributes'] = serialize($item['@attributes']);
        unset($item['@attributes']);
    }
    //подготовим запрос для вставки
    $fieldsProp = array_fill(0, count($item), '?');
    $fieldsName = array_keys($item);
    $fieldsVal = array_values($item);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO offers ( ".implode("," , $fieldsName)." ) values( ".implode("," , $fieldsProp)." );" ; 
    print_r("\n".$sql ."\n");
    //льем данные
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($fieldsVal);

}
```